# What is best way here for looping to sorting

Tags: java, loops

when i input 1 letters for here codes i got a error
 "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1"
what i should i do?

```
  static void addSchool() throws IOException {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of School: ");
            bName = br.readLine();
            bName1= bName.charAt(0);
            bName2= bName.charAt(1);
            System.out.print("Enter Address of School: ");
            bAdd = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Pricipal: ");
            pName = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Number of Students: ");
            nOS = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            newSchool = new School(bName, bAdd, pName, nOS);


            prev = null;
            curr = list;

            if(curr != null && bName1 > curr.getItems()){
                while (curr != null && bName1 == curr.getItems())
                    prev = curr;
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }
            if (curr != null && bName2 > curr.getItemss()){
                while(curr != null && bName2 == curr.getItemss())
                    prev = curr;
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }
  }
```

Comment: (Ignoring the exception for a moment) I might be reading this wrong, but it looks like neither of those while loops will ever get executed since they check for a condition that is always false in the context of the if statements they are in.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your message - you have 1 letter in the input, but you are trying to access *1st* letter (by accessing [0] element), and also *2nd* (by accessing [1] element).

Tables are numbered from 0, so no wonder you're getting `*OutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access a character which doesnt even exist in the string 
probably that line :

```
   bName2= bName.charAt(1);
```

so make sure you are trying to access a value found in the string

Answer (score 0):

`bName2= bName.charAt(1);`

You are trying to get the second char from a string, that might possibly not have more than one character in it. That's where this exception will probably be thrown. Check to make sure `bName2` is at least 2-chars long before making that call.

This is just an assumption. It would be much easier if you could tell us which line in the code generated that exception.

Comment: if(curr!=null&& bName1 >curr.getItems()){

             while (curr!=null&& bName2 > curr.getItems())
              prev = curr;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }

this is my new code. when i erase that while i input 1 letter. but i need 2 letters or more but  i cant.